# How to accept form data and return it along with the results of some processing in Django RESTFramework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to understand Django RESTFramework. I am already familiar with Django. I want to create an endpoint that accepts some text data and processes it and returns it to the user along with the results of the processing (in text). I have completed a couple of tutorials on the topic but I still don't understand how it works. Here is an example from a working tutorial project. How can I edit it to achieve my goal? It all looks automagical.

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Snippet
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer

class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
​
class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # Here I would like to accept form data and process it before returning it along with the 
    # results of the processing.
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think you are a newbie in Django rest and try to understand its flow so I can explain it with an example of a subscription plan.

First, create a model in models.py file

```py
from django.db import models

class SubscriptionPlan(models.Model):

    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    monthly_price = models.IntegerField()
    yearly_price = models.IntegerField()
```

Then create views in a view.py file like

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class SubscriptionCreateAPIView(APIView):

    serializer_class = SubscriptionSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(
            {'message': 'Subscription plan created successfully.',
                'data': serializer.data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

and then define a serializer for validation and fields in which we can verify which fields will be included in the request and response object.
serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import SubscriptionPlan


class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    plan_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    monthly_price = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    yearly_price = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SubscriptionPlan
        fields = (
            'plan_name', 'monthly_price', 'yearly_price',  
        )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return SubscriptionPlan.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Now add urls in src/subsciption_module/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import SubscriptionCreateAPIView

app_name = 'subscription_plan'

urlpatterns = [
    path('subscription_plan/', SubscriptionCreateAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

At the end include module url in root urls.py file where your main urls will be located. It will be the same directory which contains settings.py and wsgi.py files.
src/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('src.subscription_plan.urls',  namespace='subscription_plan')),

]
```

That's it. This is how flow works in django rest and you can process data and display data in this way. For more details you can refer django rest docs.

Answer (score 0):

But this is not in any way different from what you do with plain Django. Your SnippetDetail view is just a class-based view, and like any class-based view if you want to do anything specific you override the relevant method. In your case, you probably want to override `update()` to do your custom logic when receiving a PUT request to update data.

Comment: I want to create an instance. So maybe I need to override create() method. I have always used FBVs so it looks a little unfamiliar.

Comment: Well, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView does not provide create, you need a view that includes the CreateModelMixin. But I suspect a viewset would be more appropriate.